# SonarQube's Quality profile import does not succeed

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

Since I was unable to import all my rules of a quality profile via sonar web interface from production to local instance, I wanted to check if the Web services API would help do a 100% rule import. So I ran the below curl command:

```
curl -X POST -u admin:admin 
     -F 'backup=users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/bin/linux-x86-64/java-basiccodeformatting2-04347.xml' 
     -v http://localhost:9000/api/profiles/restore
```

However, when I do that, I am getting the below error. Will be greatly helpful if anybody could tell what wrong am i doing.

Below is the error trace on running the curl command

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 9000 (#0)
*   Trying ... connected
* Connected to localhost () port 9000 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /api/profiles/restore HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: localhost:9000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 241
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------eeac746cecb7
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C935E7A0048B34D1AC2EB2266179A6C1; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 31493
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2015 14:15:17 GMT
< Connection: close
<
{"err_code":500,"err_msg":"Fail to restore Quality profile backup
org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.QProfileBackuper.restore(QProfileBackuper.java:131)
org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.QProfileService.restore(QProfileService.java:142)
org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.QProfileService.restore(QProfileService.java:150)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor189.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:455)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:316)
org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:61)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190)
org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527)
org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590)
org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223)
org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$perform_action_DA0FC0A901DD1257EC969DB0C482DD8514B8F04B1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333)
rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$perform_action_DA0FC0A901DD1257EC969DB0C482DD8514B8F04B1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$call_filters_A7E1D3FFBF56E3CB7C0EBA850688505249A05AE91512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617)
rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$call_filters_A7E1D3FFBF56E3CB7C0EBA850688505249A05AE91512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:261)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:236)
rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_filters_4C7C67B4A5564FF5DC76344AF2372660F608839C1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610)
rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_filters_4C7C67B4A5564FF5DC76344AF2372660F608839C1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
rubyjit.ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451512496164.block_0$RUBY$__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68)
rubyjit$ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451512496164$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451512496164$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock.java:75)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
rubyjit.Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD91512496164.block_0$RUBY$__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17)
rubyjit$Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD91512496164$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD91512496164$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock.java:75)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
rubyjit.Benchmark$$realtime_D80759D5ED3DED92A37F972B3598DFDF9CC64E2A1512496164.__file__(jar:file:/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308)
rubyjit.Benchmark$$realtime_D80759D5ED3DED92A37F972B3598DFDF9CC64E2A1512496164.__file__(jar:file:/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:193)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.WrapperMethod.call(WrapperMethod.java:74)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
rubyjit.Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD91512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17)
rubyjit.Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD91512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
rubyjit.ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68)
rubyjit.ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
rubyjit.ActionController::Rescue$$perform_action_with_rescue_C881D7FD614DB6154FDE67AADAA1B18CFBA9E44D1512496164.chained_0_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160)
rubyjit.ActionController::Rescue$$perform_action_with_rescue_C881D7FD614DB6154FDE67AADAA1B18CFBA9E44D1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb)
rubyjit.ActionController::Rescue$$perform_action_with_rescue_C881D7FD614DB6154FDE67AADAA1B18CFBA9E44D1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
rubyjit.ActionController::Flash::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_flash_00190F39E4A509D41D1870DF577ADEFF4F2D86E01512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151)
rubyjit.ActionController::Flash::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_flash_00190F39E4A509D41D1870DF577ADEFF4F2D86E01512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:193)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:81)
org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527)
org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590)
org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223)
org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:103)
rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_0CD993B4C06E435A5AD30338E2A0816E502066551512496164.chained_0_ensure_1$RUBY$__ensure__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532)
rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_0CD993B4C06E435A5AD30338E2A0816E502066551512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_0CD993B4C06E435A5AD30338E2A0816E502066551512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:50)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:261)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:233)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:71)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:236)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:105)
rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$process_with_filters_77F73D0F3CFC9652FC1D8F99FD6ECB9ACFAEB2BE1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606)
rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$process_with_filters_77F73D0F3CFC9652FC1D8F99FD6ECB9ACFAEB2BE1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb)
org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:46)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:221)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:217)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:66)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)
rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_D1BAE9F2F7D6D00DAEDE9A175F15297655D718711512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391)
rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_D1BAE9F2F7D6D00DAEDE9A175F15297655D718711512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:221)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)
rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$call_8944B8D4A6D3AF4F57DE7885AE3EA09ADFDAED2A1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386)
rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$call_8944B8D4A6D3AF4F57DE7885AE3EA09ADFDAED2A1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
rubyjit.ActionController::Routing::RouteSet$$call_426E45DA86B30E16B94E5379DB9F140F78AE4BF41512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450)
rubyjit.ActionController::Routing::RouteSet$$call_426E45DA86B30E16B94E5379DB9F140F78AE4BF41512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$dispatch_8AA750B78C06FEA2C9269E628FA684BF9C3014791512496164.chained_1_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87)
rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$dispatch_8AA750B78C06FEA2C9269E628FA684BF9C3014791512496164.chained_0_ensure_1$RUBY$__ensure__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb)
rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$dispatch_8AA750B78C06FEA2C9269E628FA684BF9C3014791512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85)
rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$dispatch_8AA750B78C06FEA2C9269E628FA684BF9C3014791512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$_call_CD38443163AC875A33B6E9F44AC41E096715B2081512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121)
rubyjit.ActionController::Dispatcher$$_call_CD38443163AC875A33B6E9F44AC41E096715B2081512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:224)
org.jruby.RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.call(RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
rubyjit.ActiveRecord::QueryCache$$call_A14988755E65051CA93890DA44DDBD1292F522011512496164.block_0$RUBY$__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29)
rubyjit$ActiveRecord::QueryCache$$call_A14988755E65051CA93890DA44DDBD1292F522011512496164$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$ActiveRecord::QueryCache$$call_A14988755E65051CA93890DA44DDBD1292F522011512496164$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock.java:75)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
rubyjit.ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::QueryCache$$cache_A633D695A7F60465017E9EF9D11E22D24BBB2F4C1512496164.chained_0_ensure_1$RUBY$__ensure__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34)
rubyjit.ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::QueryCache$$cache_A633D695A7F60465017E9EF9D11E22D24BBB2F4C1512496164.__file__(/users/service/ecmrun/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord
```

Comment: Can you put the content of the "java-basiccodeformatting2-04347.xml" backup file on pastebin.com and reference it in your question so that I can take a look at that file please?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem was with backup file path. I corrected them and it worked.